# Merge 2 columns to 1 column with the same name

Tags: pandas

I will like to merge 2 columns into 1 column and remove nan.

I have this data:

```
     Name       A      A   
    Pikachu   2007    nan
    Pikachu   nan     2008
    Raichu    2007    nan
    Mew       nan     2018
```

Expected Result:

```
     Name     Year   
    Pikachu   2007   
    Pikachu   2008   
    Raichu    2007   
    Mew       2008
```

Code I tried:

```
df['Year']= df['A','A'].astype(str).apply(''.join,1)
```

Comment: Are they coming from different dataframes? you can't have duplicate column names on a single dataframe.

Comment: Don't do this, use a `pd.merge()` instead, when you want to join two files/datasets. See the `pd.merge` doc and figure out what your common 'on' column to join on is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (both columns cannot be same name, they have to be different, i have one as `A.1`)

```
df['year']= df.A.combine_first(df['A.1']) #this gives new column 'year', then you have to drop your existing 2 columns.

df['year']= df.pop('A').combine_first(df.pop('A.1')) #this is remove the existing columns & give a new one directly.
```

OR

```
df.bfill(axis=1) #this fills NaN's in the first column
```

OR

```
df.ffill(axis=1) #this fills NaN's in the second column
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use `ffill`

```
df['Year']=df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
df
      Name       A     A.1  Year
0  Pikachu  2007.0     NaN  2007
1  Pikachu     NaN  2008.0  2008
2   Raichu  2007.0     NaN  2007
3      Mew     NaN  2018.0  2018
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `ffill`. This is just an alternative way.  If `'nan'` is `NaN` (i.e, it's not a string) and the other values are float, you may use sum on slicing to dataframe `[['A']]`. This will slice all columns named `A` to a dataframe

```
print(df[['A']])

        A       A
0  2007.0     NaN
1     NaN  2008.0
2  2007.0     NaN
3     NaN  2018.0
```

Doing `sum` on this slicing

```
df[['A']].sum(1).astype(int)

Out[62]:
0    2007
1    2008
2    2007
3    2018
dtype: int32
```

Create a new dataframe

```
df_new = df[['Name']].assign(Year=df[['A']].sum(1).astype(int))

Out[67]:
      Name  Year
0  Pikachu  2007
1  Pikachu  2008
2   Raichu  2007
3      Mew  2018
```

---

If all `A` columns are strings, use `pd.to_numeric` to convert them to numeric type.

```
df[['A']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum(1).astype(int)

Out[97]:
0    2007
1    2008
2    2007
3    2018
dtype: int32
```